# I can't upload an app with SMS and phone call log permissions

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions, google-play-console

I have an app that reads the call log and count the SMS messages to make statistics as graphic charts, and the app requires SMS permissions and phone call log permission, and when i uploaded it on google play store ,I didn't find the approbate choice from the permissions declaration list , so i send through Google play console why i'm using these permissions and i explained to them how my app works and what it does, and the message to them was this :

"The App uses the permissions selected above to count the numbers or SMS and read phone calls log to show statistics to the user as a graphic charts.The App doesn't read, send, or receive SMS , violate user privacy or backup/store any personal information."

and they replied after days:

"We reviewed your exception request and found that it does not qualify for use of the requested permissions.

Per the Permissions policy, you may only request permissions that are necessary to implement critical current features or services in your application. You may not use permissions that give access to user or device data for undisclosed, unimplemented, or disallowed features or purposes."

any suggestions?

Screenshots:

https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/6/6/baa1a74029f0da2564a3f596d525ec33-full.png

https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/6/6/4a4b61f5d5470520a0a55eba35a642ac-full.png

Comment: I have removed permissions and feature which requires permission from app.

Comment: my app requires these permissions,without them its useless

Answer (score 1):

You cannot upload your app on Google Play store unless they grant you permission after you explain them why you actually need access to the data.

Google has started removing apps which use SMS or Call Log permission, which they consider dangerous, and will send notice to developers 90 days prior about sending a Permission Declaration form, which if accepted by Google will make your app visible in the Play Store.

They clearly state in their blog post:

> Our new policy is designed to ensure that apps asking for these
>   permissions need full and ongoing access to the sensitive data in
>   order to accomplish the app's primary use case, and that users will
>   understand why this data would be required for the app to function.

So, they'll accept your app:

1. If you remove the permissions mentioned above.
2. If the permissions are appropriate for the primary use case of the app.

Also, if your app is useless without these permissions, and Google's review team isn't granting you permission to publish on Play Store, you can do nothing about it, except maybe publish your app on different App Stores.

Answer (score 0):

Please Go through
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/reminder-smscall-log-policy-changes.html

Google has restricted apps with sms and call log permissions.